# Unable to drag my scroll bar

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

The below is chat script. When ever I try to drag up the scroll bar is pulling down. How to allow dragging in my below code.

Is there any other way to make my code better and to allow scrolling.

default.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="div1" style="height:400px; width:400px; overflow:auto; z-index:1">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="div2" style="height:300px; width:350px">
                <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div id="div4" style="position:absolute; left:500px; bottom:50px; z-index:10">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
                </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <div id="div5" style="position:absolute; left:100px; bottom:50px; z-index:10">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
            </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function _SetChatTextScrollPosition() {
            var chatText = document.getElementById("div1");
            chatText.scrollTop = chatText.scrollHeight;
            window.setTimeout("_SetChatTextScrollPosition()", 1);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            _SetChatTextScrollPosition();
        }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=chatserver;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=******;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        MyConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select message from shoutbox", MyConnection);
        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string ep = dr[0].ToString();
            values.Add(new PositionData(ep));
            BulletedList1.DataSource = values;
            BulletedList1.DataTextField = "Message";
            BulletedList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=chatserver;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=******;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO shoutbox(name, message)VALUES(?, ?)", MyConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = "gimp";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@message", OdbcType.Text).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        MyConnection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConnection.Close();
    }
}
public class PositionData
{
    private string name;

    public PositionData(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer was helpful to you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538005/unable-to-drag-my-scroll-bar/7620173#7620173

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution will be to detect if browser window is being scrolled currently by user.
If yes then don't set the scroll position, other wise do scroll the div element.

**Javascript changes**

```
var isScrolling;
document.observe('user:scrolling', function() { isScrolling = true; });

function _SetChatTextScrollPosition() {
      if(!isScrolling) {
            var chatText = document.getElementById("div1");
            chatText.scrollTop = chatText.scrollHeight;
            window.setTimeout("_SetChatTextScrollPosition()", 1);
      }
      isScrolling = false;
}
```

**HTML changes**

```
<body onscroll="document.fire('user:scrolling')">
```

[Reference link to detect the browser being window scrolled](http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1298494.htm)

Hope this helps you.

Thanks and Regards

Harsh Baid.

Comment: Have you found any solution by your own ??

Answer (score 1):

Your scrolling is not working because every 1 millisecond you are telling it to scroll to the bottom of your div1 (that's what your `_SetChatTextScrollPosition()` function does). Since your timeout wait time is so short, as soon as you let go of the scrollbar, it's going to scroll it down again.

So, if you want to be able to scroll up, you'll either have to stop using this function, or set the timeout interval to something longer (it's in milliseconds, so 1000 == 1 second) so that you at least have a chance to scroll and look before it kicks you back to the bottom.

Comment: My question is how to scroll. Not to delay scrolling. The scroll bar should be completely in my control not with update panel. If I turn off timer how chat messages won't update?

Comment: I didn't say to stop your server-side timer. I'm saying to remove the _SetChatTextScrollPosition javascript function. All it does is set the position of your div to the bottom every 1 millisecond. It has nothing to do with updating the chat messages. And it is the reason your scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: By removing that my scroll bar is resetting to TOP on timer update. :(